# Adding timestamps to pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a code that will count a number of records in a .csv file in a single hour. So, for example:

```
 data = pd.read_csv('2021-07-30.csv',  parse_dates=['time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
    datafiltr = data[data.lane == "Lane 4 Op2"]
    datafiltr['time'] = pd.to_datetime(datafiltr['time'])
    df = datafiltr['time'].groupby(datafiltr.time.dt.to_period("H")).agg('count')
```

Prints:

```
2021-08-13 13:00    18
2021-08-13 14:00    10
2021-08-13 15:00     2
2021-08-13 16:00     1
2021-08-13 17:00     2
2021-08-13 18:00     4
```

It works superbly but I need to store data in a 12-hour timespan. Something like this will be ideal:

```
2021-08-13 13:00    18
2021-08-13 14:00    10
2021-08-13 15:00     2
2021-08-13 16:00     1
2021-08-13 17:00     2
2021-08-13 18:00     4
2021-08-13 19:00     0
2021-08-13 20:00     0
...
```

But I have no idea how to approach this, please send help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried with resampling, but at least one of your time sample should be of max time to consider till there

```
df.set_index('time').resample('H').agg('count')
```

out:

```
    1   2
0       
2021-08-13 13:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 14:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 15:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 16:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 17:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 18:00:00 1   1
2021-08-13 19:00:00 0   0
2021-08-13 20:00:00 0   0
2021-08-13 21:00:00 0   0
2021-08-13 22:00:00 0   0
```

Comment: I keep getting this error:
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'
When I convert to pandas dataframe:
Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index'

Comment: if you have series, you dont need set_index i guess, would you show your series sample than output

Comment: You mean this?:
time
2021-08-13 13:00    18
Freq: H, Name: time, dtype: int64

Comment: just need Series values and series index, at least for 2 samples, so it would be easy to apply @Jukel `series.resample('H').agg('count')` did you try this, if your index it timestamp :-|

Comment: I don't know if i undestand you correctly but applying `series.resample('H').agg('count')` prints this:

`[1 1 1 1 1 1]

PeriodIndex(['2021-08-13 13:00', '2021-08-13 14:00', '2021-08-13 15:00', '2021-08-13 16:00', '2021-08-13 17:00', '2021-08-13 18:00'],
            dtype='period[H]', name='time')`

Comment: `datafilter` is a dataframe, `datafilter.set_index('time').resample('H').agg('count')` i think it must give counts